# Recovering from a HyperV snapshot being manually deleted incorrectly

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 Hyper-V (6.1.7601.17514) host which has a guest VM running in Hyper-V. The guest had 2 snapshots created after software was originally installed on it.

At some point, someone has stopped the HyperV Virtual Machine Management service and deleted a folder containing the snapshot file, restarted the HyperV Virtual Machine Management service and resumed the machine from a paused state. The machine is currently running without issue.

While the machine is up and running and is in the state I would like it, the configuration for the VM obviously still references the deleted snapshots. If I right click on a snapshot in HyperV Manager and try to delete it, understandably I get the error

> 'The specified network resource or device is no longer available'.

When I look at the VM properties and look at the hard drive properties, I can see that it points at an avhd file. However, this cannot be edited because of the warning :

> "Edit is not available because snapshots exist for this virtual
>   machine. Do not use another method to edit the virtual hard disk when
>   snapshots exist, such as the Edit Virtual Hard Disk Wizard, because
>   data loss will occur."

I would like to get this VM into a state where I can cleanly remove the snapshot references and reboot the vm, but am concerned that because of the state it is currently in, a reboot will permanently break it.

How can I recover from this scenario?